# Xamarin : Why the navigation bar not appearing

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, navigation

I have a strange behaviour about the navigation bar. I used iPhone 8 plus emulator and my iPhone 5c to run my application. All the pages will see the navigation bar but one of the client using iPhone 8plus unable to see the navigation bar on one of the screen only.

In my code, I didn't hide the navigation bar. I want to know does anyone have the same issue.

[image]

Comment: From your screenshots, it seems that the phone calling causes this problem?

Comment: That what I think too.. I might have to check it up ... Thanks.